# extract value from file USING PYTHON

Tags: python-2.7

I have one  file like

```
"keyName":"type","start":{"row":42,"column":0},"end":{"row":42,"column":3},
"keyName":"left","start":{"row":42,"column":0},"end":{"row":42,"column":3},
```

I need to extract all the values of keyname like `"keyName":"type"` and `"keyName":"left"` excluding the other values using Python.

Comment: have you tried using [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple solution just parsing it as a text file.
I do not know what you really have to do but can be efficient enough!

```
text = open("pathToMyFile", 'r').read()
split = text.split(",")
for x in split:
    if "keyName" in x:
        print x
```